# Check if the item exist in firestore db when the page renders - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-context

I'm trying to create a simple Movie app with React, Firebase as DB and I'm using the TMDB API to get the movies.

I've added the sign up and log in system to this app, so when a user signs up a new document called users gets created in the db with the email as it's id. And each user has an empty array at first where the movies will be later added as favorite movies of each user.
[Here's how the db looks like when a new user signs up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzQdM.png) [And here's how the db looks like when we add movies to it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVKQf.png)

Adding and removing on click works perfectly. Here's the code for the header.

```
import { FaHeart } from "react-icons/fa";
import { FaRegHeart } from "react-icons/fa";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { SaveMovie } from "../FavoriteHeaderContext";

const IMAGE_BASE_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_HEADER_IMAGE_BASE_URL;

const Header = ({ header_height, headerMovieData }) => {
    
    const { handleFavorite, favorite } = SaveMovie()

    return (
        <>
            <div className="relative" style={{ minHeight: header_height }}>
                <div className="z-[-1]">
                    <img
                        src={ headerMovieData ? `${ IMAGE_BASE_URL + headerMovieData.backdrop_path }` : "" }
                        className="absolute w-full h-full object-cover select-none"
                        alt="/"
                    />
                    <div className="absolute top-0 w-full h-[80%] bg-gradient-to-b from-[#0d0000] to-transparent"></div>
                    <div className="absolute bottom-0 w-full h-[20%] bg-gradient-to-t from-[#0d0000] to-transparent"></div>
                    <div className="absolute top-0 w-full h-full bg-[#0d0000]/40"></div>
                </div>

                <div className="header absolute bottom-[20%] px-[1rem] sm:px-[2rem]">
                    <h1 className="max-w-[700px] text-red-200 relative text-3xl xl:text-5xl xl:leading-[4rem] font-bold mb-6">
                        {headerMovieData
                            ? headerMovieData.title
                            : "No recommended movies"}
                    </h1>
                    ***{headerMovieData ? (
                        <button
                            onClick={() => handleFavorite(headerMovieData.id, headerMovieData)}
                            className="flex items-center gap-2 my-6 bg-[red]/30 text-white outline outline-2 outline-red-600 hover:bg-red-600 rounded-md whitespace-nowrap py-2 px-8"
                        >
                            Add to favorites
                            {favorite ? (
                                <FaHeart className="text-white" />
                            ) : (
                                <FaRegHeart className="text-white" />
                            )}
                        </button>
                    ) : (
                        ""
                    )}***
                    <p className="text-white max-w-[800px]">
                        {headerMovieData
                            ? headerMovieData.overview
                            : `We can't find movies recommended for you in our database.`}
                        {headerMovieData ? (
                            <Link
                                to={`/movie-details/${headerMovieData?.id}`}
                                className="text-red-500 cursor-pointer font-medium select-none"
                            >
                                <span> More Info...</span>
                            </Link>
                        ) : (
                            ""
                        )}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

The code between *** code *** is what you might need to take a look at here.

And here's the code for the context:

```
import { arrayUnion, doc, onSnapshot, updateDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { UserAuth } from "./AuthContext";
import { db } from "./firebase-config";

const FavoriteContext = createContext();

export default function FavoriteContextProvider({ children }) {
    const { user } = UserAuth();

    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
    const [favorite, setFavorite] = useState(false);
    const [movieID, setMovieID] = useState(undefined);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (user?.email == undefined) return;

        setMovieID(doc(db, "users", user?.email));
        onSnapshot(doc(db, "users", user?.email), (doc) => {
            setMovies(() => doc.data()?.savedShows);
        });
    }, [user?.email]);
    
    async function handleFavorite(passedID, data) {
        if (user?.email) {
            if (!favorite) {
                setFavorite(true);
                await updateDoc(movieID, {
                    savedShows: arrayUnion({
                        id: data.id,
                        title: data.title,
                        backdrop_path_img: data.backdrop_path,
                        poster_path_img: data.poster_path,
                    }),
                });
            } else {
                setFavorite(false);
                try {
                    const result = movies.filter(
                        (item) => item.id !== passedID
                    );
                    await updateDoc(movieID, {
                        savedShows: result,
                    });
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            }
        } else {
            alert("Log In to save a movie!");
        }
    }

    return (
        <FavoriteContext.Provider value={{ handleFavorite, favorite }} >
            {children}
        </FavoriteContext.Provider>
    );
}

export function SaveMovie() {
    return useContext(FavoriteContext);
}
```

As I said adding and removing movies from db works perfectly and the button changes from an outlined heart to a full heart on click.

The problem I'm trying to solve is when the page loads or renders I want to check if the movie exists in the db, if it does than I want to make the heart a full heart and if it doesn't leave it as an outlined heart.
I tried explaining the problem as best as I could
If you have more questions make sure to ask.

I'd appreciate if you can give me a hand with this since I'm still a beginner in React. (Also am I making any silly mistakes in the code?)

Answer (score 0):

Well it's hard to know exactly without knowing the structure... but I'm guessing a simple check whether it exists in the initial firebase pull...

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (user?.email == undefined) return;

    setMovieID(doc(db, "users", user?.email));
    onSnapshot(doc(db, "users", user?.email), (doc) => {
        setMovies(() => doc.data()?.savedShows);
    
      if (doc.data()?.savedShows.map(movies => movies.id).includes(yourmovieid...I don't know where you get this info from))
{
     setFavorite(true)
}

    });
}, [user?.email]);
```